# How to Show/View or Read .dwg files on browser

Tags: autocad, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, dwg, autodesk-model-derivative

How to Show or Read .dwg files on browser without using any software means using PHP, jQuery, Javascript or any other programming language.
For this I have gone through https://developer.autodesk.com and created an app with Client ID and Client Secret, Also created index.html file. But after that i get stuck in finding next movement for getting required "Model Derivative API". So Please guide me for the same. Thanks for giving your precious response.

```
<!-- The Viewer CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Developer CSS -->
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    #MyViewerDiv {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #F0F8FF;
    }
</style>
```

```
<!-- The Viewer will be instantiated here -->
<div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>

<!-- The Viewer JS -->
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

<!-- Developer JS -->
<script>
    var viewer;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        accessToken: '<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>'
    };
    var documentId = 'urn:<YOUR_URN_ID>';
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });

    /**
    * Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load() success callback.
    * Proceeds with model initialization.
    */
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {

        // A document contains references to 3D and 2D viewables.
        var viewables = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(doc.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry'}, true);
        if (viewables.length === 0) {
            console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
            return;
        }

        // Choose any of the avialble viewables
        var initialViewable = viewables[0];
        var svfUrl = doc.getViewablePath(initialViewable);
        var modelOptions = {
            sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath()
        };

        var viewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
        viewer.start(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
    }

    /**
     * Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load() failuire callback.
     */
    function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
    }

    /**
     * viewer.loadModel() success callback.
     * Invoked after the model's SVF has been initially loaded.
     * It may trigger before any geometry has been downloaded and displayed on-screen.
     */
    function onLoadModelSuccess(model) {
        console.log('onLoadModelSuccess()!');
        console.log('Validate model loaded: ' + (viewer.model === model));
        console.log(model);
    }

    /**
     * viewer.loadModel() failure callback.
     * Invoked when there's an error fetching the SVF file.
     */
    function onLoadModelError(viewerErrorCode) {
        console.error('onLoadModelError() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily test it online at [A360 Viewer](https://a360.autodesk.com/).

The code you pointed out is just the page, note how it's missing the TOKEN and the URN. In fact, following the [Viewer tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/) you'll notice a [Prepare your file for viewing](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer) tutorial.

In any case you'll need a back-end that upload and post translation jobs, we have some samples at our [github account](https://github.com/autodesk-forge/).

**Update**

Show models without programming: you can easily share your A360 models on your website, here are the steps:

1. Go to [A360](https://a360.autodesk.com/) and sign in (or sign up)
2. Use an existing project or create a new one.
3. Inside the project, click on **Upload** and select the file on your machine. The translation process will start automatically. Or you can use existing files on your project.
4. On the top-right icon, click on "Share" option. 
   [image: Share icon]
5. On the popup, go to **Embed** tab and then select the size. Copy the HTML and paste on your website. [image: Embed HTML code]

Comment: Thank you @Augusto for your reply. But i need to show dwg files on my website. For this could you please give exact link having proper guide lines like, how much pages i need to create with which type of extensions and how those pages are linked to each other for showing DWG files. I have gone through viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/samples/rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt on  https://github.com/autodesk-forge/  and it is showing nothing, So please give your further response.

Comment: Thank you so much @Augusto for your step by step guidance. Here i am able to show my DWG file ( uploaded on https://myhub.autodesk360.com and followed steps for sharing and getting embedded code) on my website. All these are static ones. But I need to show dynamic run time files , means how much file's links are there on my site, those all i could open on the fly. Please Reply for the same.

Comment: you may change the SRC attribute of the IFRAME markup on your website, but that would require some basic HTML/JavaScript coding...

Comment: As after uploading dwg files on autodesk360.com got src="https://myhub.autodesk360.com/ue2b9a926/shares/public/SH7f1edQT22b515c761ed24ca3f27f09816e?mode=embed" an alphanumeric code, and using this src only, i can show file view on my site, but i need that, if i would upload any file on my site and created a link for that uploaded file, then on click of that file's link i can show its view, for this, is it necessary that i have to upload all dwg files on autodesk360.com or any other solution to view dwg files on my website without uploading on autodesk360.com or making src dynamic ? Plz help me

Comment: Hi @Augusto , I have implemented https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs offline on my localhost (given on https://github.com/autodesk-forge/ provided by you). So could i show my own dwg files offline using forge-boilers.nodejs-master.zip code files. Thank you for your responses