# using cad 3d objects with explode function on a web page

Tags: javascript, php, cad

hello guys is there any way to use cad 3d object of a machinery in a web page and is there any way to explode that object to different parts when a user clicks on it. Pls suggest me what technology to use to make this work .

Comment: https://github.com/ghemingway/cad.js/tree/master

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274647/how-to-show-view-or-read-dwg-files-on-browser

Comment: If you need a reliable solution that works on all devices I would consider [Frame](http://www.fra.me) platform, what most of popular CAD companies are using today to make CAD available via web.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct answer to this question since it depends on what format you can export the 3d model in. But there is a lot of different 3d engines for the web, the most common I can think of is https://threejs.org/, but there is no out of the box solution for what you are asking for. It can be done but it takes some work.